# SQL: Select count of a record in right table with joins

Tags: sql, database, join, phpmyadmin

I have 2 tables one for mobiles and other is for reviews. Reviews table store the reviews of a specific mobile against its mobile id.

Structure of mobiles table.

```
mobile_id | mobile_name
```

Structure of reviews table.

```
review_id | mobile_id | review_body
```

So far I have written this query.

```
SELECT  c.*, p.review_body
FROM   ((select mobile_id, mobile_name from mobiles 
WHERE brand_id=1 limit 0,5) c)
left JOIN
(
   SELECT  mobile_id,
   MAX(review_id) MaxDate
   FROM    reviews
   GROUP BY mobile_id
) MaxDates ON c.mobile_id = MaxDates.mobile_id left JOIN
reviews p ON   MaxDates.mobile_id = p.mobile_id
AND MaxDates.MaxDate = p.review_id
```

This query returns the first 5 mobiles from mobile table and their latest (one) review from review table. This is the result it returns.

```
mobile_id | mobile_name | review_body
```

**Question:** But i also want review_count with it. review_count should be equal to total number of reviews a mobile has in reviews table against its mobile_id.

So please tell me how it can be done with a single query that I already have. Any help would be appreciated as i am trying to do this since 24 hours.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this would work

```
SELECT  c.*, p.review_body, MaxDates.review_count
FROM   ((select mobile_id, mobile_name from mobiles 
WHERE brand_id=1 limit 0,5) c)
left JOIN
(
   SELECT  mobile_id,count(review_id) review_count,
   MAX(review_id) MaxDate
   FROM    reviews
   GROUP BY mobile_id
) MaxDates ON c.mobile_id = MaxDates.mobile_id left JOIN
reviews p ON   MaxDates.mobile_id = p.mobile_id
AND MaxDates.MaxDate = p.review_id
```